# Why is money coming up with error CS0649?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When it runs it comes up with the code CS0649 which means "Field 'Moneycount.money' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null" Why is this happening?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Moneycount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    private Player money;


    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = money.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply did not set variable `money` to anything. You can initialize it to zero. i.e. `private Player money = 0`.

Comment: Assign Player script to a `GameObject` and assign that `GameObject` to your `Moneycount` script. You can also make `Player` variable public and assign Player object to it.

Comment: The error does seem rather self-explanatory.

Comment: By the way it is confusing for the Type to be `Player` but the name to be `money`, which is a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your filed `money` in your code.

you may initialize it in the constructor as below

```
public class Moneycount : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Text scoreText;
        private Player money;

        public Moneycount(Player player)
        {
            money = player;

        }
        void Update()
        {
            scoreText.text = money.ToString();
        }
    }
```

or if want to initialize with new `Player` object may use the following code.

```
public class Moneycount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    private Player money;

    public Moneycount()
    {
        money = new Player();

    }
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = money.ToString();
    }
}
```